# How to show sections on a radial progress bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I currently have a radial progress bar like a 'solid' border and I'd like to have a radial progress bar with sections (like a 'dashed' border but with more control on it).

What I'm looking for :

[image]

Here is what I have so far:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('graph'); // get canvas

var options = {
  percent: el.getAttribute('data-percent'),
  size: el.getAttribute('data-size'),
  lineWidth: el.getAttribute('data-line'),
  rotate: 0
}

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.textContent = options.percent + '%';

if (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager) !== 'undefined') {
  G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
}

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = canvas.height = options.size;

el.appendChild(span);
el.appendChild(canvas);

ctx.translate(options.size / 2, options.size / 2); // change center
ctx.rotate((-1 / 2 + options.rotate / 180) * Math.PI); // rotate -90 deg

var radius = (options.size - options.lineWidth) / 2;

var drawCircle = function(color, lineWidth, percent) {
  percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, percent || 1), 1);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 * percent, false);
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round'; // butt, round or square
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
  ctx.stroke();
};

drawCircle('#57d39d', options.lineWidth, 100 / 100);
drawCircle('#14928e', options.lineWidth, options.percent / 100);
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
span {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  line-height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 110px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart" id="graph" data-percent="30" data-size="110" data-line="6"></div>
```

Comment: [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/sLzzss41/)  another way to do your arc-progress bar in html5 canvas.

Comment: Thanks, very nice too ! =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can quite literally use a dash pattern. Just calculate the dash pattern based on the circle's circumference:

Assuming the variables are declared:

```js
radius = 140;
circum = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
gap = 7;
sections = 5;
dashOn = circum / sections - gap;
```

Then set the dash-pattern this way:

```js
ctx.setLineDash([dashOn, gap]);    // set dash pattern
ctx.lineDashOffset = -gap * 0.5;   // center dash gap
```

I you want to have the first gap/section pointing up you just need to rotate the context -90° first.

**Update**: If you want rounded caps for each segment, simply active this by doing:

```
ctx.lineCap = "round";
```

However, the "cap" will consume part of the gap so we need to compensate the size of the gap by adding the line width to the gap value.

### Example

Shows how to set and remove the dash-pattern, and demonstrates how to rotate the context so that the sections are drawn from the top position, as well as how to make rounded caps.

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    radius = 140,
    circum = 2 * Math.PI * radius,
    lineWidth = 12,
    gap = 9 + lineWidth;                         // compensate for rounded caps

function render() {
  var sections = s.max = +seg.value;
  var dashOn = circum / sections - gap;
  var t = +s.value / sections;                   // normalize value on sections

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);                 // clear previous drawn content
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1, 150, 150);           // translate to center
  ctx.rotate(-Math.PI*0.5);                      // rotate -90° so 0° is up

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0,0,radius, Math.PI*2*t, Math.PI*2);   // circle from angle x t
  ctx.setLineDash([dashOn, gap]);                // set dash pattern
  ctx.lineDashOffset = -gap * 0.5;               // center dash gap
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;                     // line width
  ctx.lineCap = "round";                         // line width
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#9ac";                      // base color
  ctx.stroke();                                  // render it
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI*2 * t);       // render arc based on angle x t
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#06c";                      // top color
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.setLineDash([]);                           // reset dash
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);                 // reset transforms
  // render text here
}

(s.oninput = seg.oninput = render)();            // demo slider and first run
```

```html
<label>Segments: <input id=seg type=range min=3 max=40 value=5></label><br>
<label>Progress: <input id=s type=range min=0 max=5 value=0></label><br>
<canvas id=c height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: That is awesome !! Do you think it is possible to 'round' the edges of the lines ?

Comment: I like the use of variable, it makes it very modular. =)

Comment: @Elfayer true, and I couldn't resist update the answer showing this aspect too.

Answer (score 3):

inspired from a [sass & haml](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/details/ulsqJ) pen :

[Demo](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EKzJKd) and plain HTML/CSS below in snippet

```css
.boo {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -35px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: lime;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.boo:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(-71deg) translate(70px);
}
.boo:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(1deg) translate(70px);
}
.boo:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(73deg) translate(70px);
}
.boo:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(145deg) translate(70px);
}
.boo:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(217deg) translate(70px);
}

.a1 .boo + .boo {
  background: gray;
}

.a2 .boo:nth-child(2) ~ .boo {
  background: gray;
}

.a3 .boo:nth-child(3) ~ .boo {
  background: gray;
}

.a4 .boo:nth-child(4) ~ .boo {
  background: gray;
}

.a1:after {
  content: '1/5';
}

.a2:after {
  content: '2/5';
}

.a3:after {
  content: '3/5';
}

.a4:after {
  content: '4/5';
}

.a5:after {
  content: '5/5';
}

.gge {
  float: left;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 10px ;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gge:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 50% 0;
  margin-left: -0.25em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 2;
}

.gge:after {
  line-height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
}

.boo:before,
.boo:after {
  left: auto;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 16px;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transform: rotate(-35deg);
}

.boo:before {
  top: -7px;
  right: 21px;
}

.boo:after {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  bottom: -7px;
  right: 21px;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='gge a1'>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
</div>
<div class='gge a2'>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
</div>
<div class='gge a3'>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
</div>
<div class='gge a4'>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
</div>
<div class='gge a5'>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
  <div class='boo'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Very instructive though I'd have liked to use the same model for both so it does mingle well. I might start again from your model to create a full radial progress bar. Also, do you have any idea how to add the 'rounded' effect on edges ? I thought of adding an element with `border-radius: 50%;` at the correct positions.

Comment: @Elfayer , this was the good idea i believe, each visual bars can generates 2 pseudos : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EKzJKd (snippet also updated)

Comment: @markE  turn the background / clip into only a pseudo , looks better in my IE, about yours ?  http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EKzJKd

Comment: Nice full HTML solution, but it seems complicated to change the number of sections dynamically. ie: https://jsfiddle.net/mt62m95q/1/

Comment: It can be usable if sass is involved and sections updated before loading, progression can be applied via setting the class on the fly :) . else , just plain html/CSS is not flexible enough indeed, SVG would be much more flexible and would allow even animation from a point to another :)